# What's the best way to make my website compatible with all screen sizes?

Tags: html, size, screen, compatibility

I'm not even talking about mobile (just yet), I set widths and heights that are based on the pixel count of my laptop's display, but on my desktop 22" monitor, everything's out of place, div lines are too short (larger display, so it makes sense), etc.

I'm thinking I should use strictly percents, so instead of "width:200px", it'd be "width:64%", would that be a good solution?

Also, I see some websites, they adjust the content when you shrink the browser window (looks like an effect of "margin:0 auto", just keeping things centered), but also, when the width gets small enough, it just stops adjusting, it stops because moving any more and the content will start moving to lines below it in order to fit... How can I get this same effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by making your site "responsive" which basically means that you use a grid system that scales and the screen size changes.

There are a couple of frameworks out there that help with this. My favorite is Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/) but there are others like bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/)

There is a ton of documentation on these sites you should focus on the grid sections:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: It certainly does help, thank you.  I'm going for Foundation- to be clear I just download the "Default CSS" file, and put CSS code into my primary CSS file?

Comment: Okay, no it doesn't look quite that simple...  It looks like I have to remake my website with the grid system?

Comment: To have a truly responsive site you should code it using some sort of grid system. You could address certain parts of your site but it is usually best to use the grid from the beginning. So you don't necessarily have to recode your site for the grid, it's usually a good idea (or at least parts of it). Also, important to note that you can embed the grid in certain areas and those areas would be responsive.

Answer (score 1):

There are websites using the responsive layout. Means you have orientations/everything fixed for the mobile screens, tablets as well as full size pc/laptop screens.

They make use of a grid system.
Common ones are

- Twitter Bootstrap (Two different versions having different UI and
  approaches are available at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ and
  http://getbootstrap.com/) This one's my favourite as its too easy to
  use
- [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/)
- [html5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)
- [Sprout Core](http://sproutcore.com/)
- [Less Framework](http://lessframework.com/)

You may pick any one you like. They all provide a basic css and javascript to handle things out nicely, a wireframe of a complete website is provided and an extremely well documented manual is available on their websites. Its actually fun and makes work faster. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One useful and recommanded unit is the viewport percentage length that will adjust accordingly.

for example to get a div the size of the window and another div on top of the first one:

```
            <div id='one-page'></div>
            <div id='inside'></div>

              #one-page{
                 width:100vw;
                 height:100vh;
                 background:red;
                position:relative;              
               }
             #inside{
                width:10vw;
                height:10vh;
                background:black;
                position:absolute;
                top:10vh;
                left:20vw;    
             }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xv7Yf/